# burning smell when using miter saw

Tags: tools, miter

I just bought a ryobi 15 Amp 12 in. Sliding Miter Saw with Laser.  I never use miter saw before. Cut a few 2x4 to learn how to use it.  The problem is everytime I cut, I get a "burning" smell. Not sure if its normal or blade touched other metal parts caused that burning smell.

I also adjusted the depth. I don't think blade touched anything. but still get burning smell.

Comment: Burning wood or burning electronics? Any blackening of the cut face?

Comment: i cannot really tell. didn't see any blackening of the cut face. also checked miter saw, didn't see anything burned.

Answer (score 3):

It's burning wood you smell. If it's not a new saw, the issue is likely that the blade is dull. Time for a new blade.

If it's a new saw, it could be that you're cutting too fast through too hard of wood.

Comment: its new. unboxed today. I never use miter saw before, today is the first time, I dont really know what to do, so cut it pretty slow

Comment: Was the blade premounted? Reaching way back in time, I recall when the correct direction for blades/teeth seemed backwards to me.

Comment: @Ecnerwal ah! Good catch...yes, be sure the blade is on correctly!