# Burning smell on new miter saw - pre-installed blade

Tags: woodworking, miter

I bought a new Dewalt miter saw and every time I use it, there is a burning smell. I saw [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90237/burning-smell-when-using-miter-saw) about a similar issue, but I don't think my problem is the speed at which I'm cutting or the thickness of the wood (doing test cuts on a 2x2 and have made cuts a varying speeds to make sure I wasn't cutting too fast).

A quick internet search suggests this can happen when the blade is dull or when the blade is on backwards. However, my miter saw actually came with the blade pre-installed, and the teeth are facing the correct way. Also, I don't think the blade a new miter saw comes with would be dull, but maybe I am wrong.

The other thing that puzzles me is I'm not actually seeing burn marks on the wood. Anyways, I was hoping to get some advice on some additional things I could check to determine what is causing this burning smell. Also, are the blades that usually ship with Dewalt miter saws good quality, or should I go ahead and replace it?

Comment: Re:"are the blades that usually ship with Dewalt miter saws good quality" Dewalt is like many manufacturers. You can spend little and get low-end consumer-grade products from them, or you can spend a lot and get high-end tradesmen tools from them.

Comment: If it is new, it should be under warranty. Find an authorized repair shop near you and bring it in.

Comment: I own a DeWalt compound miter saw. The first thing I did after setting it up was to replace the blade with a finishing blade (more teeth, smoother cut). The blade it came with was fairly awful.

Comment: Is the blade secured tightly? Maybe you should loosen and re-tighten the blade.

Comment: yes, it's secured tightly. I am going to replace the blade and if  it doesn't fix the issue I will contact an authorized repair shop as @mikeazo suggests